# Twitter typeahead not working after upgrade

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, upgrade, typeahead.js

I upgraded twitter typeahead using the nuget package manager from 10.2 to 1.11 and the remote query is no longer being called to get the autocomplete results in my ASP.Net MVC 5 project. There are no errors reported.

```
var engine = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('FullName'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    limit: 10,
    remote: '/Person/GetPeople?q=%QUERY'
});

engine.initialize();

$('#Person').typeahead({
    hint: true,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 1,
}, {
    display: 'FullName',
    source: engine.ttAdapter()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer before I finished typing my question out, so here is what I found. I just had to change the `remote` declaration in the following:

```
var engine = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('FullName'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    limit: 10,
    remote: {
        url: '/Person/GetPeople?q=%QUERY',
        wildcard: '%QUERY'
    }
});
```

Furthermore, the CSS was broken for Bootstrap 3 - I am using [typeahead.js-bootstrap3.less](https://github.com/hyspace/typeahead.js-bootstrap3.less). The temporary fix for this was to replace `dropdown-menu` with `menu` in `typeahead.css` (until a new release).